# What is the difference between "it will be destroyed." and "it will get destroyed."?

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between "it will get destroyed." and "it will be destroyed."?Are they both equivalent?

Comment: Although it's now idiomatic and commonplace, using ***get*** in such contexts is a bit "downmarket", so you should probably avoid it in formal contexts. Also note that it's still not idiomatic for all contexts - for example, *If I fail I will **get disappointed*** is unlikely. And *The turkey will **get cooked** at midday tomorrow* is more likely to carry the sense of  ***starting*** to be cooked (it'll go ***in*** the oven at that time), whereas ***will be cooked*** probably means that's when it will be ***ready to eat*** (it'll come ***out*** of the oven).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was [cross-posted to ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/233850/can-get-and-be-be-interchangeable-or-not).

Comment: One thing you can bank on is if you are in an area where both are used, they are not equivalent. When used with a verb like *destroyed* that tends to imply a willful agent destroyer, *get* is used to distance the speaker from having a willful role in the destruction. If there is a fire, the files will get destroyed. After seven years, the files will be destroyed anyway.

Comment: @tchrist Eh? It may be off topic, and it may be cross posted, but it isn't off topic because it was cross posted.

Comment: @PhilSweet Fixed that for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using "get" in formal contexts.

Although "be" is better, you can also use:

> it will become destroyed

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *get* in formal contexts. The OPs sentence is an example of the passive *get*, and you indeed should avoid many uses of the passive *get,* including this one, in formal contexts. But the people who say *"don't use get"* have somehow a̶c̶q̶u̶i̶r̶e̶d̶,̶ ̶o̶b̶t̶a̶i̶n̶e̶d̶,̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶o̶m̶e̶ gotten the wrong idea.

Comment: Getting destroyed and being destroyed seem to be similar to me.